# Prevent logging of environmental variables in sudo

Tags: cron, sudo, env

I'm trying to provide a secret value to a script, via an environmental variable, but not have it logged by `sudo` in `auth.log`.

At the moment I have the file:

```
/etc/secret-key
export SECRET_CONFIG_KEY=K1PX7MZ8an8H2mRQR
```

This file is owned by root:root (0400).

Using `cron` and `sudo`, I can run the script under the `www-data` user, and provide this value.

```
5 * * * * root . /etc/secret-key; sudo -u www-data --preserve-env=SECRET_CONFIG_KEY /path/to/script
```

But the `auth.log` file then contains lines such as:

```
Aug 19 18:30:01 server sudo: root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=www-data ; ENV=SECRET_CONFIG_KEY=K1PX7MZ8an8H2mRQR ; COMMAND=/path/to/script
```

Which is readable by anyone in the `adm` group, and emailed to me every day via LogWatch.

---

I'm happy to consider alternative approaches.

The main feature is providing this secret value to a script, using the `www-data` account, where that account is only given access to this value as needed (the account should not have read access to the secret-key file).

As a side note, the `www-data` account cannot edit any of its scripts, the account is only used to run them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using `su` rather than `sudo` for this.

Consider something like:

```
su www-data -w SECRET_CONFIG_KEY -c /path/to/script
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to tweak it a bit to:
`5 * * * * root . /etc/secret-key; su www-data -s /bin/bash -p -c '/path/to/script'`
But that's because my server sets `/usr/sbin/nologin` for the shell, only has `-p` to "preserve the current environment", and needed quote marks because the full command was a bit more complicated.